# Extracting data from excel cells based on words before the required data

Tags: excel

I have extracted outlook emails into an excel format but I have so far been unable ( using the basic methods) to extract the contents of these cells into seperate columns.

The outlook extract bulks together all of the data in the "body" of the email into one cell.

When you look at one of the cells the data appears in once continuous string, but if you expand the cell you can see the data appears in a format similar to the below

```
Email: Test@test.com
Name: Dave

Submitted: Thursday 2 February

Surname: Test
```

What I need to do is extract from each cell the "name" and "email",  the data that comes after "Email:" and "Name:", into separate columns.

I can't use the Trim or Left/Right functions because each email address and submit date is slightly different in length.

If anyone is able to help I would be very grateful.

Comment: have you try my answer ? .. any comment ?

Answer (score 0):

Assumed that the text in A1 ....

You may put this formula ...

B1 = `=MID($A$1;1;FIND("Name";$A$1)-1)`

B2 = `=MID($A$1;FIND("Name";$A$1);FIND("Submitted";$A$1)-FIND("Name";$A$1))`

B3 = `=MID($A$1;FIND("Submitted";$A$1);FIND("Surname";$A$1)-FIND("Submitted";$A$1))`

B4 = `=MID($A$1;FIND("Surname";$A$1);LEN($A$1)-FIND("Surname";$A$1)+1)`